# Array elements not allocating by positive or negative values in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, memory-management

Basically I'm just trying to sort all user input numbers by positive or negative. So far I'm just trying to create an array of only positive integers, but can't seem to get it right.

Been stuck on this for a while and can't quite understand why my program is allocating negative integers to my array that's supposed to be for positive integers only, despite my if statements instructing otherwise. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {   
    int num_of_elements = 0, i, j, x;
    int elements[num_of_elements];
    int positive_total = 0, negative_total = 0;
    int negative_elements[20];
    int positive_elements[20];

    printf("How many elements in N? \n:");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_elements);

    for (i=0; i<num_of_elements; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter element a%d. \n:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &elements[i]);
    }

    for (j=0; j<num_of_elements; j++)
    {
        if (elements[j] > 0)
        {
            positive_elements[positive_total] = elements[j];
            positive_total++;
        } else if (elements[j] < 0) {
            negative_elements[negative_total] = elements[j];
            negative_total++;
        }
    }

    int num;
    for (num=0; num<=positive_total;num++) {
        printf("\npositive element %d is %d", num, positive_elements[num]);
    }

    int MAX_pos_element = 0;

    for (x=0; x<=positive_total; x++) {     
        if (MAX_pos_element < positive_elements[x]) {
            MAX_pos_element = positive_elements[x];
            printf("\n%d is larger than %d", MAX_pos_element, positive_elements[x]);
            printf("\nelement[%d] has the largest value: %d", x, MAX_pos_element);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `num<=positive_total` you should use `<` because indices go from `0..n-1` in your program.

Comment: I love you @PaulOgilvie <3 dumb mistake from my part. thanks for noticing, everything works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
int num_of_elements = 0, i, j, x;
int elements[num_of_elements];
```

you are allocating an array of *zero* length because `num_of_elements` is still zero.

Use the following:

```
printf("How many elements in N? \n:");
scanf("%d", &num_of_elements);
int elements[num_of_elements];
```

Now `num_of_elements` is initialized.

(Note: you should also check the return value of `scanf` to be sure a number was read.)

Answer (score 0):

The program is initially invalid and has undefined behavior.

You may not declare a variable length array with zero number of elements as you are doing

```
int num_of_elements = 0, i, j, x;
int elements[num_of_elements];
```

You should declare the array after you entered a positive value of the variable `num_of_elements`.

For example

```
printf("How many elements in N? \n:");
scanf("%d", &num_of_elements);

int elements[num_of_elements];
```

Also in loops like this

```
for (num=0; num<=positive_total;num++) {
    printf("\npositive element %d is %d", num, positive_elements[num]);
}
```

you have to use the condition `num < positive_total` instead of `num <= positive_total`.